# select data from mysql (with for loop(?)) in R

Tags: mysql, r, apply

What I want is:

```
m1 <- dbGetQuery(mydb, "select out,in from table where value > 1")
m2 <- dbGetQuery(mydb, "select out,in from table where value > 1.1")
m3 <- dbGetQuery(mydb, "select out,in from table where value > 1.2")
m4 <- dbGetQuery(mydb, "select out,in from table where value > 1.3")
                                .
                                .
                                .
m101 <- dbGetQuery(mydb, "select out,in from table where value > 10")
```

then

```
n1 <- degree(graph.data.frame(m)) 
n2 <- degree(graph.data.frame(m2)
            .
            .
            .
```

I would like to simplify these codes with apply function but I have no clue :^(

Comment: The sequence of `value` that you'll query... is it the complete sequence? If so, then you can query the DB for any value and subset latter the data frame...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `for` loop solution that saves the results in a list:

```
# get list
myList <- list()

for(i in seq(1, 10, 0.1)) {
  myList[[paste0("m",i)]]<- dbGetQuery(mydb, 
                               paste("select out,in from table where value >", i))
}
```

You can then call the objects out of you list:

```
n1 <- degree(graph.data.frame(myList[["m1"]]))
```

and as above, you can put these results in a list. Named lists are a great way to store and organize many objects.